# Generating JAR on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dll, jar

I have some problems while creating a jar of my intelliJ project. First of all I just do the usual procedure:

1. Go to project structure
2. Select artifacts
3. Create a new one with modules and dependecies
4. Go to build artifact, build it
5. Execute it at console with java -jar "ddddd.jar"

So when I execute the project (not the jar) all runs ok, libreries and all works, but not in the JAR.

**Terminal of IntelliJ:**
[image]

My libraries are located in the project like: project>lib>"some jars here">otherjars>"here some jars and respective dll

This is because the "other jars" need the dll to work. I already tried to run them without the .dll but doesn't work without it.

Also I have them in the project on Modules>Dependencies I have the folder selected as a library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:

Here I add some pictures about how I have my libraries structured.

[image]

[image]

Comment: DLLs packed inside the jar will not work out of the box. You need to write the code to unpack them into the temp location and load from there. See how JNA library does it. Another option is to place the DLLs in PATH or in some other location that you can supply using the -Djava.library.path JVM option.

Comment: hey @CrazyCoder i already tried to put them in a directory and load them via JVM but nothing changed

Comment: Share the sample project showing how you load the libraries and from where.

Comment: @CrazyCoder here i added how i have the libraries, the error is that flsx needs the dll to work and it's not working on the jar, but yes on the normal execution of the project

Comment: The `.dll` file must be in one of the following: 1) working directory 2) system `PATH` environment 3) a directory specified via `-Djava.library.path` JVM option.

Comment: so if I move the .dll to the project path it should work right?

Comment: If you project path is one of the 3 mentioned above, then yes.

Comment: so my last question is: Executing the jar via terminal of intelliJ is the same than running by clicking on it on the project?

Comment: Using `java -jar …` and IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug configuration of the Application type works completely different.

Comment: now I tried to execute my jar without java-jar and it opens the project but it doesn't work